# Need to figure out how to do the math for deck of cards using different searches.

Tags: probability, algorithms

Below are the two questions I found from the websites ( I have added the link below ), that I am interested in learning the answers. My intention are not to post the answers for that guy but, I recently coded Linear search, jump search, binary search and linked list search. I found these question about deck of cards for jump and linear search. I am very bad at math and I don't play cards. So, if anyone can help me understand these or help me do it, I would like to code these as well. I don't know if I have to deal with probabilities or use the formulas like (n+1)/2 for average cost linear search. So, any help will be highly appreciated.

1. In a shuffled deck of 52 cards, we remove 1 card (we don’t know which one) and use LINEAR SEARCH to find the two of clubs.
   a. What is the average cost to find the two of clubs, if it is guaranteed to be in the deck?
   b. What is the average cost if the two of clubs is equally likely to be in the deck, or not in the 
   deck?
   c. What is the average cost if it is equally likely that the 2 of clubs is not in the deck or that it is 
   in the deck?
   d. What is the average cost if the card that was removed was the 2 of clubs?
2. In an ordered (A – K, ♠♢♣♡) 52 card deck, using JUMP SEARCH, looking for the queen of hearts.
   a. What is the optimum jump size k?
   b. How many probes (m) will it take with the optimum jump size?
   c. What is the worst case number of comparisons using k and m? 
         **http://www.jiskha.com/display.cgi?id=1405366630**  **http://www.jiskha.com/display.cgi?id=1405366918**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1a. This is simply 51/2, or 25.5, as statistically, you need to search half the deck before you find the card.

1b.

- 50% chance of it being in the deck: This is simply problem 1a. (25.5)
- 50% chance of it not being in the deck: In this case, it will search the entire deck, which takes a cost of 51. 
  Thus, (25.5 + 51) / 2 =  38.25

1c. Isn't this the same as 1b? I'm guessing you mean that this is before a card is picked, in which case it's:

- 1/52 chance the card is not in the deck.
- 51/52 chance the card is in the deck: Thus, we do (1/52) * 51 + (51/52) * 25.5 = ~25.99

1d. 51, because it will always take an entire search before finding it.

Not sure about 2, but just trying to contribute what I can. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I was thinking the same way for number 1. But again since the average cost for linear search is (n+1)/2 = (51 + 1)/2 = 26 which is almost equal to n/2. I wasn't sure which way I needed to go.

Comment: Again,the average cost of searching a shuffled deck of 52 cards with LINEAR SEARCH to find the jack of diamonds is (n+1)/2 = (52+1)/2= 26.5. If I have to find, any card in the suit of hearts: will it be 52-13=39. (39+1)/2= 20? Or since the probability is 13/52 = 1/4. I simply divide the 26.5 by 1/4? Sorry these are simple questions but always eat my brain.

Comment: Yes, the chances of picking a card of a specific suit from a shuffled deck of 52 cards is 1/4, and thus it will take an average of 4 cards before you hit a specific suit.

Keep in mind, however, I am an amateur math person, so don't take my word for it. You should probably check with other people. :)